# direct limit of finitely generated submodule

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

If $A$ is a module, then the family $\mathrm{fin}(A)$ of all the finitely generated submodules of $A$ is a directed set and the direct limit of the modules $M_i$ is isomorphic to $A$. To prove this, we needed to define an injection from $M_j$ to $M_i$. Is it true define inclusion map for injection? This means that $M_i$=$\sum_1^n Rm_i $ such that the $m_i$ generate $M_i$. Define $\Gamma_i^j\colon M_j\to  M_j$ if $M_j \subseteq M_i$? If we define it then the direct limit of $M_i$ is $\oplus _i$$M_i$. How do we show that $A \cong \oplus _i M_i$?

Answer (score 5):

Order the set of finitely generated sub-$A$-modules of $M$ by inclusion. This gives you a directed system $(S,\subseteq)$ of (finitely generated) sub-$A$-modules of $M$, and the direct limit of this set is isomorphic to $M$. You can see this as simply saying that the union of all finitely generated submodules of $M$ is equal to $M$, which is intuitively trivially true indeed.

Indeed, it is injective, as if you are zero in the limit/union of the $M'$'s for $M'\in S$, it means that you are zero in some $M'\in S$, and this means that you are zero. It is surjective because any element $m$ of $M$ is an $M'$ such that $M'\in S$ : just take for $M'$ the sub-$A$-module of $M$ generated by $m$.